# New Tub Lip problem

Tags: bathtub

In my guest bath remodel, I have taken old tub and tile out, and put new tub and concrete board in. My problem is, tub lip is out in front of concrete board on tub sides about a quarter inch maybe a bit more, and not flush with concrete board. God help me if there isnt a simple fix.....lol   HELP !

Comment: the lip of the tub is supposed to be behind the concrete board, with the board overlapping the lip of the tub

Comment: @jsotola I would expand this into an answer I agree the lip goes behind but with it out in front it sounds like the tub was not located correctly by 1/2"

Answer (score 1):

I am not God but i play one on the world wide intertubes.

What thickness cement board did you use ?

Please provide a detailed explanation of what work you have done, did you demo down to the studs etc.

You could take the cement board off and put some furring strips of the appropriate thickness on the studs and then re-install the cement board.

If you used 1/4 inch board You could replace it with 1/2 inch

You could add more cement board over the top of the other with longer screws.

Either way you are making the wall thicker in the shower area than the drywall next to it so you will need to determine how you are going to transition from the tile the the drywall. ( furr all of the wall so it is equal? or some funky step down transition? )

I use denshield for a tile backer in a shower because it is the same thickness as drywall so not funky transitions are needed. ( plus it has a waterproof barrier on it. )